# Adding more than one folder at once to the Music Library in Windows Media Player

Tags: file-management, music, windows-media-player

I was adding folders to Windows Media Player Music Library (via Manage Music Library) and since I have too many music folders, I wondered if there is a way to add them all at once to the Library. It will be a real time saver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an easy way to do it - choose the folders you want to add and drag and drop them in the Folder View of the Music Library.

Answer (score 1):

To make it clear: The Windows Media Music Library is actually the Music Library of your Windows system. Apart from using the GUI that comes with Windows, you can also use alternative command-line tools to add a folder to a library.

Here is an article that lists some of such tools: http://www.grimadmin.com/article.php/creating-modifying-windows-7-libraries ([download](http://www.grimadmin.com/filemgmt/index.php?id=5) `shlib` and `slutil`))

As an example, you can add a folder to the Music Library using `shlib` like this:

```
shlib add "%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Libraries\Music.library-ms" "C:\Files\Audio\01\Skrileks"
```

Using `slutil`, it would look like that:

```
slutil addfolder Music "C:\Files\Audio\01\Skrileks"
```

To add more than one folder, you can create and run a batch file.