# Win 7, show two folders as one?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have two hard drives (one internal, one usb, both connected to the same PC), each has a 'movies' folder. Can I somehow view both 'movies' folders in one folder as though all files resided together?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Windows 7, that's exactly what the "Libraries" are for.

You probably even already have a "Videos" library, you just need to add the folders you wish to include in that library.

[image: Windows Explorer Libraries]

More information from Microsoft on using Libraries in Windows 7: [Libraries](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-CA/windows7/products/features/libraries)

Blurb:

> Libraries—new in Windows 7—make it easier to find, work with, and
>   organize files scattered across your PC or network. A library brings
>   your stuff together in one place—no matter where it's actually stored.

Perhaps also check out this related SU question: [Adding more than one folder at once to the Music Library in Windows Media Player](https://superuser.com/questions/592145/adding-more-than-one-folder-at-once-to-the-music-library-in-windows-media-player)

Comment: techie007: I like the libraries feature but I don't like how the two HDs are separated, any way to combine to make it look like it's truely just one folder? http://i.imgur.com/bmzbfPd.png

Comment: Right click -> `Arange by` -> anything but folder. Edited my answer.

Comment: You should also note that Libraries have the possibility to set a default location. So when you create something new within the library it goes to this location.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click at `Videos` library, select `properties`, click `Add` and find the video folder you want to add. Repeat once more to add the second folder. You'll have them both appear under "Videos" now. To 'merge' 2 groups, right click -> `Arange by` -> select anything but folder.

Note: I'm using Windows 8 atm, but I believe the process is very similar, if not the same, in windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have 2 movie folders because of the limited space on both of the drives, and you want some way of merging both of the files together to have 1 clean list of movies so you can browse your list. If So, in the physical sense, you obviously can't.

But what you can do is make a folder on your desktop, make shortcuts of all the folders or files, and that will give you the entire list or playlist of your movies in 1 list in that folder on your desktop

Answer (score 0):

This is very possible through the magic of symbolic links. Unlike shortcuts,  symbolic links behave exactly like the real files allowing you to watch and edit all your movies like they were placed on the same drive.

There are quite a few tools available to help creating such links, for example [Symlink Creator](https://code.google.com/p/symlinker/downloads/list). You might have to google though, to find one that suits your needs better.

Comment: Symlinks just stop working when the item they point to is deleted.

Comment: @BlacklightShining You're right. When I tested it out for my reply the links disappeared after deleting the source files. I probably created a folder junction instead of a sym link.