# Can I create link that points to many folders

Tags: windows-7, windows, symbolic-link

I'm under Windows 7, and I'd like to know if it's possible to create a virtual folder that points to many other folders, effectively listing all their contents as if being in a  single directory.

I'll try to be more precise with an example. 
Let's suppose that I have many files in a directory structure to better categorize them, like this:

```
Main_dir
|-> Subfolder1
|   |-> File1A.zip
|   |-> File1B.zip
|-> Subfolder2
|   |-> File2A.zip
|   |-> File2B.zip
|-> Subfolder3
    |-> File3A.zip
    |-> File3B.zip
```

And so on. I need to keep those files inside this hierarchical structure, like I said to have them categorized; but I also need to have all of them listed as being inside a single directory, like this:

```
Virtual_dir
|-> File1A.zip
|-> File1B.zip
|-> File2A.zip
|-> File2B.zip
|-> File3A.zip
|-> File3B.zip
```

Basically, I want to create a link named `Virtual_dir` that points to `Main_dir\Subfolder1` AND `Main_dir\Subfolder2` AND `Main_dir\Subfolder3`.

Is it possible to do so? Linking any single file inside the `Virtual_dir` is not what I'm trying to do. I want to use a feature similar to [libraries](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/working-with-libraries), with folder containing any kind of files (not just music, videos and documents) in a way that can be understood not just by Windows itsefl but also by any other arbitrary piece of software.

Comment: Also see: [Win 7, show two folders as one?](http://superuser.com/questions/645737/win-7-show-two-folders-as-one)

Comment: Libraries are more or less what I need, but how can I get the full URL of, in example, the `Documents` library? I need to paste it inside a configuration file to make a certain software recognize it, but if I try to get it from Explorer address bar I get something like `Libraries\Documents`, that is not a full URL and is not recognized outside Windows explorer.

Comment: [Can I browse windows 7 libraries from the command prompt?](http://superuser.com/questions/203639/can-i-browse-windows-7-libraries-from-the-command-prompt)