# How can I Link two folders together. Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, sync, shared-folders

How can I Link two folders together. Similar to bridging in a network. But. More of a clone. (two different locations, same address)

Comment: Hi, welcome on superuser. Try always to search before you ask a question, maybe you can find directly the answer `;)` [Give it a look here](http://superuser.com/questions/645737/win-7-show-two-folders-as-one). Ps> if the answers there are not enough, please [edit] your post and add details... Ok [edit] the question and add details...

Answer (score 0):

This command should do the job:

```
mklink /D Downloads d:\downloads
```

It might require administrative privileges, though.